# putting strings in ssh2_exec

Tags: php, ssh2-exec

I am having touble with ssh2_exec putting strings in execute.

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'userad '. $user. ' -p  '. $password);
doesnt work



$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'userad  user -p  password');
works
```

Comment: may be it is useradd

Comment: Hopefully your password has special characters in it, in which case you should use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) on it first.

Comment: $password = escapeshellarg( crypt('password') );

Answer (score 1):

what i did to fix this was this;

```
$command = 'useradd ' .$user. ' -p '. $password;
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
```